# changing the state of a clicked button within a google maps infobox

Tags: jquery, button, google-maps-api-3, onclick

I've run into a problem changing the state of my infobox's buttons when clicked.  I have three states for each of the six buttons within the infobox menu:  unclicked, hover, and clicked.  The buttons change to the clicked state, but for some reason they don't change back when clicked again.  Therefore, I've located my problem to the if statement within the buttonState() function that's called on each click.  Once I solve this problem I'll be adding another function to the onClick of each button, telling the infobox which piece of  dynamic information to display.  I'll also have to figure out how to make sure only one button is in the "clicked" state at one time.  Any help with that would be great as well.

As you can see, I'm new to jquery and javascript.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you very much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript"src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?        key=MY_KEY&sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery191.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="infobox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var mapstyle = [styles removed for space]

var icon = 'mapicon.png';
var map = null;


//<![CDATA[

function mapload() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40,-95),
    zoom: 4,
    minZoom: 4,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    styles: mapstyle,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

downloadUrl("genxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var places = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("place");
        for (var x = 0; x < places.length; x++) {
        var name = places[x].getAttribute("name");
        var logopath = places[x].getAttribute("logopath");
        var number = places[x].getAttribute("number");
        var street = places[x].getAttribute("street");
        var city = places[x].getAttribute("city");
        var website = places[x].getAttribute("website");
        var phone = places[x].getAttribute("phone");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(places[x].getAttribute("lat")),
            parseFloat(places[x].getAttribute("lng")));
        createMarker(name, logopath, number, street, city, website, phone, point);
        }

});
}

function createMarker(name, logopath, number, street, city, website, phone, point) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon,
        title: name
  });

  var boxContent = "<div id=box><div id=leftside><img id=logo src=" + 
                    logopath + " /><h1>" + number + "<br />" + street + 
                    "<br />" + city + "</h1><h2>" + phone + 
                    "<br /><a target=_blank href=" + website + 
                    ">visit website</a></h2></div><div id=menu>" +
                    "<button id=photos onClick=buttonState(this.id)>" +
                    "</button><button id=comments onClick=buttonState(this.id)>" +
                    "</button><button id=games onClick=buttonState(this.id)></button>" +
                    "<button id=ed onClick=buttonState(this.id)></button>" +
                    "<button id=stay onClick=buttonState(this.id)></button>" +
                    "<button id=fly onClick=buttonState(this.id)></button>" +
                    "</div><div id=display><button id=next></button><button id=prev></button></div></div>";
  var myOptions = {
        content: boxContent,
        disableAutoPan: false,
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-400, -173),
        closeBoxMargin: "-12px -12px 0px 0px",
        closeBoxURL: "close.png",
        infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
        pane: "floatPane",
        enableEventPropagation: false
   };

  var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
        map.setZoom(13);
        map.setCenter(this.getPosition());                      
        ib.open(map, this);
  });

}

function buttonState(buttonid){

if ($('#' + buttonid).css('background-image') === 'url(infomenu/' + buttonid + '-click.png)') {
    $('#' + buttonid).css('background-image','url(infomenu/' + buttonid + '.png)')
 }   
 else {
    $('#' + buttonid).css('background-image','url(infomenu/' + buttonid + '-click.png)'); 
     }  
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
  new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
  new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
        }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>

</script>

</head>
<body onload="mapload()">
   <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
   <div id="logosearch"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think what you need is jQuery [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: I do think that's probably the best solution too.  However, I'm not sure how to implement it with multiple buttons, each of which have different icons.  would you mind providing a sample of how this might be done?

Comment: right now i have the icons attached to the background image.  I guess what i could do i separate the image and add it to the button, keeping the background (the part that has the state change) free for manipulation.  i'll come back with a solution if i can manage.

Answer (score 0):

thanks chriz

```
function buttonState(buttonid){

    $('button').not(buttonid).removeClass('down');
    $('button#'+ buttonid).toggleClass('down');
```